# Move folder in all git branches

Tags: git

We have a central repo with 20 branches, they all use layout like:

```
/.gitignore
/file1.txt
/file2.txt
```

Now this should be changed to

```
/.gitignore
/ProjectFolder/file1.txt
/ProjectFolder/file2.txt
```

**in all branches**. How would you approach that in git? Do the change in all branches? Merge everything to master and rename only there? Is there some magical command to batch rename in all branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scripting provided by your system and apply the commands to all branches in a `for` cycle.

Something like this in `bash`:

```
for i in $branches; do
   git checkout $i
   ....
   git commit -m "moved files"
done
```

Comment: You'll probably want to join all of the commands inside the for loop with `&&`, and tack an `|| exit 1` on the end, so that it doesn't charge ahead if it runs into problems.