# How do I keep my local branches up to date

Tags: git

I have a several branches in my repository and I'm finding that over time it's becoming more difficult to keep them all up to date. I can always be sure that master is up to date because it's easy to remember and I suppose it's my SVN mentality still lingering on.

- master

  - bugfix1
  - bugfix2
  - newfeature

    - experiment

My problem is something like this. I make changes in the bugfix2 branch, I merge the changes in to master once I've done my commit, but then I have several other branches out of date. I have to manually merge bugfix2 in to every other branch. As my branch list grows, I think it's unrealistic to perform all these merge operations.

Is there a command for this or is my workflow wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general workflow is to merge from the most specific branch to a less specific branch.
But for [a bug needed to be reported to *all* other branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325064/move-folder-in-all-git-branches), a simple merge to the other branches is enough and can be scripted (even aliased):

```
for i in $branches; do
   git checkout $i
   git merge bugfix2
done
```

Comment: This automates is somewhat. There's just something that doesn't sit right. Useful solution though, I'll stick to this for the time being.

Comment: @Vince: usually, what kind be "not right" is the lack of relationship between branches (you don't know what to merge from which branch to which branch). A good branch naming convention can help.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to merge whatever you need into whatever branch you're currently working on, and don't worry about keeping the rest up to date until the next time you work on them. One of the reasons I use git locally on top of my company's centralized VCS is that it allows branches to be a little out of date. The bug that's hard to reproduce can be worked against the exact version it was reported against. New features can be debugged without wondering if it was your change that caused the problem or the update you just pulled down in order to push a separate fix. By all means, don't let your branches diverge too far from `master`, but don't be religious about keeping them always up to date "just because."  Update them at the best time for the individual branch.

Answer (score -1):

My suggested workflow would be to rebase your bugfix branches on master, once master goes ahead. So your history remains clean and doesn't contain that much merge commits.

Comment: It ain't good practice. A bugfix is made at a specific codebase state, rebasing it on master makes it a "floating commit", and you loose the knowledge about when it was applied. Better merge it in other branches

Comment: Well, in case of the bugfix branches, you are right. For feature branches, like the newfeature branch in his example, my workflow would be the better choice. And i didn't mean to rebase a bugfix branch once it was merged. But if you are working on your bugfix branch (which wasn't merged yet), and you want the current changes of master, why shouldn't you rebase? Is the information, when the bugfix branch was started, really needed?

Comment: Rebasing feature branches is OK; as for bugfixes: it's important to know what state it does correct. Also, rebasing them can lead to other bugs, so it gets a more complex history.